# Bean validation regex for an input string containing x or y number of digits

Tags: java, regex, validation, bean-validation

I want to check if an input string contains x or y number of digits. I am using `JSR-303` bean validation. Is it possible to check? If yes what regex would be appropriate? For. eg. "123dfn5657" or "34fdg8959413" if validating against something like "^(\d{7}|\d{9})$" should be valid.

Comment: You can read about [Spring MVC Form Validation with Bean Validation API](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-mvc/7127/spring-mvc-validation#t=201610030839208452712).

Comment: Do you refer to "digit" as "character", either a number of a letter?

Comment: @RamónGilMoreno In the question above total number of digits present in string "123dfn5657" are -- 7. So a digit is just a character in the input string.

Comment: Your initial description of the question is misleading as you want to filter any letter in your input and retain only the digits/numbers. Please be more specific on your description next time. I have updated my answer to skip letters while accounting the total amount of digits/numbers/0-9 in your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expressions syntax as described in the [`java.util.regex.Pattern` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In your case, say you want, for instance, to define inputs of 1, 2 or 4 digits (but not 3), you can use a construction like this:

```
String[] samples = { 
    "1",
    "12",
    "1234",
    "123",
    "123a",
    "1a234",
    "a1234b",
    "a1bcd2e",
    "a1bcd2e3",
    "a1bde2e34"
};
for (String s: samples) {
    System.out.println(s + "\t" +
            java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("(([a-z]*\\d){1}|([a-z]*\\d){2}|([a-z]*\\d){4})[a-z]*", s));
}
```

And the output will be:

```
1         true
12        true
1234      true
123       false
123a      false
1a234     true
a1234b    true
a1bcd2e   true
a1bcd2e3  false
a1bde2e34 true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using bean validation's `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`. And I tried @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{5} | \\d{6}"). But this does not seem to work. Rather than \\d multiple times I want to specify length which would be more easy.

Comment: I think the spaces in your regexp are causing it to fail. I updated my answer to setup the construction you want by using quantifiers.

Comment: Not using spaces in code. I am giving an input string like the "68jjdn780" and it fails for regex in my above comment. I want some regex which would see given number of digits(integers) only in a string and overlook everything else. I have edited my question for the same. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: I have updated my answer to filter out the letters while accounting the total number of digits in your input. It is done by matching (optionally) any sequence of letters before a digit, and finally adding an extra optional match   to discard the trailing letters. Note that I used quite a lot of parenthesis to limit the scope of each section in the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try to be more specific in my description.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to test your JSR303 annotated bean using https://github.com/flexguse/validation-violation-checker, which is a little JUnit addon.

If you use Eclipse as your IDE I recommend the QuickRex Plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quickrex.

With these two tools you should be very fast in trial and error to create your regular expression, which could be

```
[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try both. BTW will your regex work for any input size?? The size of input is not known.

Comment: Yes, this regexp should work for any input size, there must be at least one leading digit followed by at least one character followed by at least one digut.